# Quote block has syntax highlighting as if it were code

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, blockquote

I just finished updating an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571902/use-with-xmlvm-to-convert-android-app-to-iphone-app/5571972#5571972) and I noticed that a big quote block has syntax highlighting. I did hit the code button originally but then I switched it to quote and now you can clearly see the `>` characters on the left side of the paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I further improved the formatting of your answer based on the documents you referenced; hope you don't mind.

I think by copying directly from the PDF, the content in your second quote block got indented enough to form a code block *within the quote block*, hence the coloring.

Anyway, I usually avoid using the quote button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as it breaks a paragraph into many lines and prepends `>` to all of them, making it very hard to format correctly when there are other elements such as code blocks or lists. Instead I prepend `>` by hand to *each paragraph*. Formatting by hand always makes things easier — unless you're talking about indenting code blocks of course, in which case I still use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: I just noticed the change. Of course I don't mind. So if it's not a bug, should the question be deleted?

Comment: @Aleadam, Would you mind accepting BoltClock's answer instead of deleting?

Comment: @Aleadam: You can retag it as either `discussion` or `support`, perhaps.

Comment: @YOU is there a tag for non-bug or similar instead? (Edit: I type too slow)

Comment: @Aleadam, BoltClock already answered above. `support` would be good one IMHO :-)

Answer (score 1):

blockquote and code block could be nested, so your edits is appears in html like this

```
<blockquote>
     <pre class="default prettyprint">
          <code>
                .......
```

If you think you set wrong formatting, you should undo it first, for example, hit code block button(ctrl+k) to undo code block and hit blockquote button (ctrl+q) to make blockquote.

Comment: Sorry I retagged it. I did not mean `<blockquote>` , but the simpler "> this is quote" block

Comment: @Aleadam: He's referring to the HTML that's generated by your Markdown.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm such a noob :)